# Prestashop Webservice order processing

Tags: web-services, rest, prestashop

Can anyone tell me how to insert a order in Prestashop using webservice??

I tried filling blank schema and it always returns xml parsing error.

Comment: Prestashop Version : PrestaShop™ 1.6.0.9

Comment: exception 'PrestaShopWebserviceException' with message 'HTTP XML response is not parsable : array ( 0 => LibXMLError::__set_state(array( 'level' => 3, 'code' => 4, 'column' => 1, 'message' => 'Start tag expected, \'<\' not found ', 'file' => '', 'line' => 1, )), )'

Answer (score 0):

Blank xml file would not be acceptable. Fill the fields and then try..